# Angular 2 not loading test component

Tags: angular, typescript

I got my app.component working in Angular 2 but I can't seem to get a test one working. It doesn't get past the "Loading..." message in my html. Could someone please review my code and see where I went wrong? I thought I followed the course I was watching perfectly but nothing seems to appear.

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MyComponent} from './my-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

    <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><my-component>
    </my-component>`,

directives: [MyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

my-component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component ({
selector: 'my-component',
template: `<h2>Hello World</h2>`

})

export class MyComponent {
}
```

index.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
<title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
 </script>
  </head>

  <body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

Comment: What is the console showing?  `./my-component.component';`

 not found?

Comment: @JS_astronauts That's right, "app/app.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module './my-component.component'."

Comment: just check your path. Are both component files inside same directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// The code Look to be fine But its seems to be one issue from my point of View at now

// If name of my-component.ts: is name of file

// Then in app component you should import it

```
    import {MyComponent} from './my-component';
```

// You have done it

```
    import {MyComponent} from './my-component**.component**';
```

// .compomnent is not needed while import angular handle it with annotations

// For more about import [Click Here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html#!#stq=import&stp=1)

Comment: Thank you, removing the extension fixed the problem.